# ChartView how to align with xAxis boundaries

Tags: qt, charts, qml

I'd like to align an item with ChartView's X axis boundary. [image]

Is it possible and please give me a tip how to do it?
Current solution does not look nice at all :

```
         Rectangle {
            color : "darkgrey"
            anchors.top : parent.top
            x : itemPlot.x + 50
            width : parent.width - 50 - 20
            height : parent.height*0.6
         }

         ChartView {
            id : itemPlot

            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.left: parent.left
            width : parent.width
            height : parent.height*0.4


            legend.visible: false
            antialiasing: true
            margins.bottom : 0
            margins.top : 0
            margins.left : 0
            margins.right : 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use `plotArea` property of `ChartView` :

```
 Rectangle {
    color : "darkgrey"
    anchors.top : parent.top
    x : itemSpectrumPlot.plotArea.x
    width : itemSpectrumPlot.plotArea.width
    height : parent.height*0.6
 }
```